# Angular & Nginx in Docker container behind Nginx on Host

Tags: angular, docker, express, nginx

I have built an Angular App along with an Express based API. In testing i have been using docker compose to run the built angular app in an nginx container, the express api and a mongodb container.

I am currently trying to deploy the application to a server that already has gitlab installed with nginx bundled. I have followed the documentation to add a custom rule to the host nginx. I tested that the config worked by creating a simple 'hello world' express app and forwarding '/test' to port 4200 so my page was displayed.

I am trying to configure things so that if you go to www.mydomain.com you get gitlab as normal but if you go to www.mydomain.com/test you go to my angular application.

A sub-domain is an option but i have no experience in doing that with nginx.

I tried to see if i could get the host nginx to forward to docker nginx and it kind of worked but the file url's were wrong instead of going to 'www.mydomain.com/test/styles.css' it was trying 'www.mydomain.com/styles.css' which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add `--baseHref="/test"` option to an `ng build` command, and everything should work fine